# Flutter: How to close keyboard on onSubmitted() for TextField without lost focus

Tags: flutter, keyboard, focus, textfield, readonly

I have a TextField widget, After submit `onSubmitted()` I want to keep focusing on this TextField with **`readonly = false`** but in the same time I want to minimize the keyboard or close it, I can't use

```
 FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

or

```
 FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
```

or

```
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

When the onSubmit is called, keyboard will be disabled because readOnly is true but TextField would have the focus.
But when you tap on the TextField, keyboard will appear because now readOnly is false and the it already had the focus

```
 class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      bool read = false;
    
      FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            title: 'Flutter Demo',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: TextField(
                    onTap: () {
                      read = false;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                    focusNode: focusNode,
                    readOnly: read,
                    cursorColor: Colors.blue,
                    onSubmitted: (val) async {
                      print(val);
                      read = true;
                      focusNode.requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```